# Target class [Database\Seeders\RoleTableSeeder] does not exist

Tags: php, laravel

So I've been creating a CMS with Laravel and when I run this command to migrate the tables

```
php artisan migrate:fresh --seed
```

I've been experiencing this error

```
Dropped all tables successfully.
Migration table created successfully.
Migrating: 2014_10_12_000000_create_users_table
Migrated:  2014_10_12_000000_create_users_table (70.61ms)
Migrating: 2014_10_12_100000_create_password_resets_table
Migrated:  2014_10_12_100000_create_password_resets_table (96.25ms)
Migrating: 2019_08_19_000000_create_failed_jobs_table
Migrated:  2019_08_19_000000_create_failed_jobs_table (96.25ms)
Migrating: 2021_06_07_163133_create_roles_table
Migrated:  2021_06_07_163133_create_roles_table (40.94ms)
Migrating: 2021_06_07_163453_create_role_user_table
Migrated:  2021_06_07_163453_create_role_user_table (42.74ms)

   Illuminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException

  Target class [Database\Seeders\RoleTableSeeder] does not exist.

  at C:\Users\bdhef\activecodeproject\blogbear\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php:838
    834▕
    835▕         try {
    836▕             $reflector = new ReflectionClass($concrete);
    837▕         } catch (ReflectionException $e) {
  ➜ 838▕             throw new BindingResolutionException("Target class [$concrete] does not exist.", 0, $e);
    839▕         }
    840▕
    841▕         // If the type is not instantiable, the developer is attempting to resolve
    842▕         // an abstract type such as an Interface or Abstract Class and there is

  1   C:\Users\bdhef\activecodeproject\blogbear\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php:836
      ReflectionException::("Class "Database\Seeders\RoleTableSeeder" does not exist")

  2   C:\Users\bdhef\activecodeproject\blogbear\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php:836
      ReflectionClass::__construct("Database\Seeders\RoleTableSeeder")
```

I've tried searching to see if someone has the same problem as me, but there seem to be no similar problems. I also can't tell if the migrations went through or not.

EDIT:
Here is the seeder class

```
<?php

use App\Models\Role;
use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

class RoleTableSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        $role_regular_user = new Role;
        $role_regular_user->name = 'user';
        $role_regular_user->description = 'A regular user';
        $role_regular_user->save();
    
        $role_admin_user = new Role;
        $role_admin_user->name = 'admin';
        $role_admin_user->description = 'An admin user';
        $role_admin_user->save();
    }
}
```

Here is the project structure

```
app
-> Console
-> Exceptions
-> Http
-> Models
  -> Role.php
-> Providers
database
-> Factories
-> Migrations
-> Seeders
  RoleTableSeeder.php
```

Comment: Anytime you (or I) see "Target class xxx does not exist" the first two steps should be: 1) check and double check the namespaces in your class. 2) dump the composer autoload.

Comment: can you please show the seeder class as well as the directory structure of you project

Comment: I edited the question to add the class and directory structure. I didn't add the entire structure, just the structure for the two files I'm having trouble with

Comment: Your `RoleTableSeeder` doesn't have a `namespace ...`

Comment: Where should the namespace be pointing to?

Comment: The path of the file, so typically `namespace App\Database\Seeds`, but it can be whatever you define, like `namespace Database\Seeders`, or `namespace Database\Seeds`, etc etc. As long as you reference it properly when you use it  (and it looks like Seeders are slightly different, answer below demonstrates perfectly)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the docs https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/upgrade#seeder-factory-namespaces

```php
<?php

//  add this line 
namespace Database\Seeders;

use App\Models\Role;
use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

class RoleTableSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        $role_regular_user = new Role;
        $role_regular_user->name = 'user';
        $role_regular_user->description = 'A regular user';
        $role_regular_user->save();
    
        $role_admin_user = new Role;
        $role_admin_user->name = 'admin';
        $role_admin_user->description = 'An admin user';
        $role_admin_user->save();
    }
}
```

Also just as a Laravel TIP

Instead of

```php
$role_regular_user = new Role;
$role_regular_user->name = 'user';
$role_regular_user->description = 'A regular user';
$role_regular_user->save();
```

Consider using

```php
$role_regular_user = Role::create([
    'name' => 'user',
    'description' => 'A regular user',
]);
```

It's much cleaner

Don't forget to add `$fillable` property in you `Role` model